# Retrieve related table and select fields from primary table using Laravel Artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

In the following code, The Users table has a related table phoneNumbers. When I retrieve a list of all users like this,

```
return Person::with('phoneNumbers')->get();
```

everything works fine. However, when I attempt to specify a list of columns to return from the Person table, the phone_number returns empty.

```
 return Person::with('phoneNumbers')
          ->get(['fname','lname', 'email']);
```

If I add the number field or phone_number.number to the get array, then I get an error as an undefined column. What is the laravel way of handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Person::select(['your_foreign_key', 'fname','lname', 'email'])
->with('phoneNumbers')get();
```

Comment: I'm still getting an empty array for phone_numbers

Comment: What is the fk for the relation? Place it inside the select and it should work

Comment: Thanks Giovanni, You are correct. For anyone who stumbles upon this, both of the following work.  return Person::with('phoneNumbers')
              ->get(['id','fname','lname', 'email']);
       return Person::select(['id', 'fname','lname', 'email'])
             ->with('phoneNumbers')->get();